# Можно ли так выразиться?

Tags: грамотная-речь, синтаксис, согласование, единственное-множественное-число, счетный-оборот

Мы с женой на родительском собрании ждали, когда освободится преподаватель, чтобы задать ему интересующий нас вопрос. Ожидание длилось довольно долго, и жена уже хотела уходить. Я сказал ей, что ещё пару минут ожидания нас не устроят, и поэтому мы можем ещё подождать. После жена стала со мной спорить, что так по-русски нельзя сказать: "пару минут ожидания нас не устроят".
В общем, у нас спор: можно или нельзя так выразится?
Большая просьба: помогите разрешить его.

Заранее большое спасибо!

Comment: Аргументы стороны не выдвигали?

Comment: Может, "устроят", а не "не устроят"? Где логика (*и поэтому...*)?

Answer (score 1):

Раз есть "*время ожидания*", то думаю, что корректно и "*минуты ожидания*".

Answer (score 1):

А. *Пара минут* — именно такая форма (то есть именительный падеж) требуется в предложении, потому что это подлежащее.

Б. Сказуемое желательно использовать в единственном числе — *не устроит*.

> **13.** При наличии в составе подлежащего имени существительного со значением определенного количества (***тройка, сотня, пара*** и т. п.) сказуемое ставится в форме единственного числа, например: ***Семерка велосипедистов устремилась** вперед; **Сотня ребят разбежалась** во все стороны.*

Глагол ["устроить"](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C) в этом предложении имеет такое значение:
**6.** Подойти кому-либо, быть удобным для кого-либо, удовлетворить. *Обслуживание устроило туристов. Квартира устроила новосёлов*

Правильно нужно было сказать так:
*Ещё пара минут ожидания нас не устроит.*

В. Примеры:
***Пара минут ожидания показалась** для Максима очень большим промежутком времени* (М. Рощин. Визуализатор).
*Думаю, **пара минут ожидания не повредит** ни нам, ни этому экземпляру* (К. Жевнов. Фантастические сказки на ночь).
***Пара минут ожидания показалась** ему вечностью* (Р. Алиев. Эффекты).

[§184. Сказуемое при подлежащем — количественно-именном сочетании (счетном обороте)](https://orfogrammka.ru/OGL02/70091268.html#:%7E:text=%D0%9F%D0%BE%20%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%83%20%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B5%20%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%83%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F,%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BE%20%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%8B%D0%BC%D0%B8%20%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%20(%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%8E%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87).)

Comment: Эта норма постепенно устаревает. Например, вообще не слышал, чтобы так говорили.

Comment: Ну-у... Если вы не слышали, то вот: *А **пройдет** пара минут, очнешься немного ― все, пусто* (Д. Глуховский, 2005); *И если пара минут **будет потрачена** на их разъяснения...  **Проходит** пара минут* (Т. Соломатина, 2011); *Еще пара минут **ушла** на то, чтобы выйти к подъезду* (Н. Леонов, 2001).

Comment: Имею в виду, что похоже на то, что количество людей, кто так говорит, постепенно уменьшается. Введите в Google "прошло пару минут" и второй вариант и сравните количество результатов.

Comment: Никуда и никак оно (*количество людей, кто так говорит*) не уменьшается! Вы же никогда так (во множественном числе) не скажете: тройка лошадей помчались; четверка спасателей прилетели. Правда?

Comment: С "пара" **уже** другая история. У этого слова появляется значение "несколько", а когда именно две, то говорят по-другому, да и скажут: *Прошло две минуты.*

Comment: Зачем же нам "прошло"? У нас ведь "не устроят" — множественное число. Или Вы предполагаете, что надо было сказать так: *Ещё пара минут ожидания нас **не устроило***?

Comment: Так, конечно, не получается, надо так: *Ещё пар**у** минут ожидания нас не устроило.* Но такая структура плохо подходит для прошедшего времени, плохая стилистика, лучше переформулировать: *Нас не устроило ждать ещё пару минут.* И это значение даже не появляется, а уже зафиксировано в словарях, хоть и *разг.* пока что.

Comment: *При наличии в составе подлежащего имени существительного со значением определенного количества* — вот именно, что определённого, а здесь значение — *несколько*.

Answer (score 0):

Тут спор между формальностями и реальной практикой. При этом формальности должны быть подстроены под практику, а не наоборот. Чем и займемся.

Сначала ответим на что-нибудь попроще

```
Много минут нас не устроят/устроит
```

Подлежащее может быть выражено косвенным падежом в случае **приблизительного** числа. При этом сказуемое может стоять как в единственном числе (много кораблей вышло из гавани), так, видимо, и во множественном (много облаков плыли по небу).

Теперь еще один простой эксперимент:

```
Нас устроило бы пара минут
```

Фраза очевидно неверная и нужно

```
Нас устроила бы пара минут
```

Но людям хочется сказать в косвенном падеже, подразумевая под парой **сколько-то**. Поэтому и говорят

```
Нас устроило/устроили бы пару минут
```

Почему же здесь винительный падеж? Потому, что только винительный отвечает на вопрос **сколько**.

```
Я имел (сколько?) пару минут
```

Итого, фраза на мой взгляд корректная, ибо

1. Использование словосочетания в косвенном падеже в качестве подлежащего в случае выражения приблизительного количества - стандартная практика в РЯ.
2. Косвенный падеж для пары подойдет только винительный, потому что именно он отвечает на вопрос `сколько мы имели минут`

Comment: *Подлежащее может быть выражено косвенным падежом в случае **приблизительного** числа.* "Много кораблей", "много облаков" — это счетные обороты (см.: https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/lingvistic/587/%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5) в именительном падеже, где "много" — собирательное, а не количественное (два) числительное или существительное со значением определенного количества (пара).

Comment: Не вопрос: Подлежащее может быть выражено косвенным падежом в том случае, если оно указывает на приблизительное количество кого-либо или чего-либо. Ср.: Тридцать кораблей вышло в море. Около тридцати кораблей вышло в море. Свыше тридцати кораблей вышло в море.

Comment: *много облаков плыли по небу* — это некорректно, такое используется, когда говорят о людях.

Comment: @190920 *Подлежащее может быть выражено косвенным падежом...* Вы ошибаетесь, повторю: подлежащее "много кораблей" стоит в именительном падеже. Вот косвенные падежи счетного оборота: многих кораблей (Р. п.), многим кораблям (Д. п.), многими кораблями (Т. п.)...

Comment: Косвенный падеж это "свыше тридцати кораблей", аналогично "с пару минут" или просто "пару минут". Это пример из учебников, если что